# Specify domain classes directories in Grails

Tags: grails, grails-domain-class

Is there a way to specify the directory in which Grails looks for domain classes? I want to have grails enhance domain classes from `grails-app/domain` as well as `test/domain`, when running in the test environment.

The reason I need this is that I have some domain classes which I use in a plugin for integration tests. They currently sit in `grails-app/domain` under a specific package. In the plugin descriptor I ensure that this package is excluded from the plugin build. This works fine when it is packaged as a plugin, however for various reasons we run and build our app with this plugin declared inline in `BuildConfig.xml`. This causes those domain classes to be compiled into the host application, despite the exclusion declared in the plugin descriptor - so they are deployed with the application and tables are generated for them, which I don't want.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you running the application as a WAR when you are testing? I ask because it's pretty easy to remove resources from the staging directory when the WAR is being created. Let me know if you want me to explain further on how that is done.